# How get value of object by map key?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, javascript-objects

I have a map structure where key is array and values is objects.

```
myMap = new Map();
myMap.set(["_1030002", "_1030003"], { name: "Yayay", description: "aaa", floor: -3});
```

How to get values of objects by one key?

For example how to get value of 'floor' by key "_1030003"?

My provider store.ts:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { JsonStoresDataInterface } from './../../providers/stores/stores';

@Injectable()
export class StoresProvider {

    private JsonStoresData = new Map();
    defaultKey  = "_1030003";
    url_request = "path/to/json";


  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getStoresRemote(){
        this.http.get<JsonStoresDataInterface>(this.url_request).subscribe(data => {
            var json = data.data;
            for (var store of json.stores){
                this.JsonStoresData.set(store.polygon_id, {
                        name: store.name,
                        description: store.description,
                        floor: store.floor[0],
                        image: store.pic_info.src,
                        uid: store.uid
                        })
            }
        });

                console.log(this.JsonStoresData);//ok map
                let keys = Array.from(this.JsonStoresData.keys());
            let key = keys.find(key => key.includes(this.defaultKey));
            console.log(this.JsonStoresData.get(key).floor);
       //TypeError: Cannot read property 'floor' of undefined


}
}
```

Comment: `console.log(???)` The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: at least a bit of effort for pasting your data structure well as source code.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `keys()` method. The *`keys()`* method `returns` a new *Iterator* object that contains the keys for each element in the `Map` object in insertion order.

Since an `Iterator` object is returned, you need to use `Array.from` method.

We need to use `includes` method in order to find the `map's` key which contains key `_1030003` as in your question.

```js
myMap = new Map();
myMap.set(["_1030002", "_1030003"], { name: "Yayay", description: "aaa", floor: -3});
let keys = Array.from(myMap.keys());
let key = keys.find(key => key.includes("_1030003"));
console.log(myMap.get(key).floor);
```

Another problem you have is that you're not correctly handling *asynchronous* request. Since `get` operation is executed asynchronous, the `console.log(this.JsonStoresData);` will be executed before the request call finished.

One solution could be using a *callback* function.

```
getRequest(callback){
    this.http.get<JsonStoresDataInterface>(this.url_request).subscribe(data => {
        var json = data.data;
        for (var store of json.stores){
            this.JsonStoresData.set(store.polygon_id, {
                    name: store.name,
                    description: store.description,
                    floor: store.floor[0],
                    image: store.pic_info.src,
                    uid: store.uid
                    })
        }
        callback(this.JsonStoresData)
    });
}
 getStoresRemote(){
      let def_key = this.defaultKey;
      getRequest(function(data){
          let keys = Array.from(data.keys());
          let key = keys.find(key => key.includes(def_key));
          console.log(data.get(key).floor);
      });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but I got error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Comment: @НикитаМеркушев, I updated my answer

Comment: @ MihaiAlexandru-Ionut still got error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'floor' of undefined`. I updated my post with full code. May be something wrong with json parsing

Comment: @НикитаМеркушев, I suppose that `console.log(this.JsonStoresData)` logs empty map.

Comment: @НикитаМеркушев, have a look to my updated answer.

Comment: can you please also show how to return data from provider getStoresRemote() to component?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call